# Apache NiFi - Rest API endpoints to list all the available endpoints and endpoint for data provenance and monitoring

Tags: apache-nifi, endpoint

I'm new to Apache NiFi. I have set my properties

```
 nifi.web.http.host=127.0.0.1
 nifi.web.http.port=8085
 nifi.web.http.network.interface.default= 
 nifi.web.api.enabled=true
```

also I have,

```
# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
```

I can see the data provenance in nifi, but I would like to have an endpoint for the same and others to monitoring using some BI tools or other tools.

I can see the response for http://localhost:8085/nifi-api/system-diagnostics. But I need something like http://localhost:8085/nifi-api/provenance-events. Also is there anyway I can find the list of available endpoints?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html is one, but couldnt find one for provenance